# Field is required frombody post

Tags: asp.net-core

Getting an error binding the DataTables AjaxSettings model.  I've looked at a couple examples and tried them both, and both of them have the same error.   I'm basically just copying and pasting code.  Not sure why this isn't working.

I have the following model. (copied, link at the top).

```
//https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching
namespace Claims.Features.DataTables.Models;

public class DataTableAjaxPostModel
{
    // properties are not capital due to json mapping
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

Controller signature:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "PostListClaims")]
public IEnumerable<Maps.ClaimDto> Post([FromBody]DataTableAjaxPostModel ajaxSettings)
```

Call:

```
return this.httpClient.post<ListClaimsResponse>(`${environment.apiServer}ListClaims`, ajaxSettings);
```

```
{
  "ajaxSettings": {
    "draw": 1,
    "columns": [
      {
        "data": "id",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": false
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "firstName",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": false
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "lastName",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "order": [
      {
        "column": 0,
        "dir": "asc"
      }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "length": 10,
    "search": {
      "value": "",
      "regex": false
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-d150cacc0c8dd9595402c753e0ced79c-56544a4e3615c810-00",
  "errors": {
    "Order": [
      "The Order field is required."
    ],
    "Search": [
      "The Search field is required."
    ],
    "Columns": [
      "The Columns field is required."
    ],
    "SortOrder": [
      "The SortOrder field is required."
    ],
    "AdditionalValues": [
      "The AdditionalValues field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:

This works.  It's not because of the capitalization because I generated this automatically from the post body using a Convert JSON to C# site, and it initially used lowercase and that also worked.  I reverted to the original model and changed the name of the object to AjaxSettings, and that didn't work.  So I don't know what the difference is.

```
public class AjaxSettings
{
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public Search Search { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public Search Search { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Regex { get; set; }
}
```

```
[HttpPost(Name = "PostListClaims")]
public IEnumerable<Maps.ClaimDto> Post([FromBody]AjaxSettings ajaxSettings)
```

```
return this.httpClient.post<ListClaimsResponse>(`${environment.apiServer}ListClaims`, ajaxSettings);
```

Comment: it's sort of telling that SortOrder and AdditionalValues are not in your posted model code.  It seems to be expecting a different model.  (trying to map to a data-model instead of your view model?)

Comment: Can u Mention the Target Frame work version

Comment: @UpenderReddy 7

Comment: there is difference in 7 vs before 5 string will be nullable type. make `string` as `string?` and remaining too or make `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in `.csproj` file

Comment: @UpenderReddy, how does that affect my code?  The code looks the same; doesn't it?  Neither schema has nullable types.

Comment: just a note:  ASP.NET will ignore case for incoming var names....  so case shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Bluebaron there is changes in new version try this way may help you don't come to conclusions with out try

Comment: @UpenderReddy do you think if I turn my computer off and on again it might work?

Comment: Try that way also Mr. /Mis. @Bluebaron if it works then you can chill out no need of trying.

Comment: @UpenderReddy I actually solved this a while ago by using a JSON to C# class translator, but I just can't imagine what use throwing darts at a dartboard would do if you don't understand what you're trying to do or why or how it might work.

Comment: @Bluebaron if it's Resolved you should mention some where how u got resolution. if any  other person got he/she will comes to conclusion. comment section is not a place to play sarcasm. use this platform for resolutions

Comment: @UpenderReddy, I did on July 19.  "Edit: This works ..."

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues here:

1. You are posting the data wrapped in another object which is not represented in your code. Either try posting data without wrapper:

   ```cs
   return this.httpClient.post<ListClaimsResponse>(`${environment.apiServer}ListClaims`, ajaxSettings);
   ```

   or add corresponding class and accept it in the action:

   ```cs
   public class Root
   {
       public DataTableAjaxPostModel ajaxSettings { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   ```cs
   [HttpPost(Name = "PostListClaims")]
   public IEnumerable<Maps.ClaimDto> Post([FromBody] Root ajaxSettings)
   ```
2. Potentially you will need to update the `Search` model (`System.Text.Json` can be picky about types used):

   ```cs
   public class Search
   {
       public string value { get; set; }
       public bool regex { get; set; } // <- here
   }
   ```

P.S.

Try following the standard [C# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), i.e. Pascal case property names and let the serializer figure the name conversion (actually for web apps it should be able to handle this out of the box as far as I remember).

Comment: Agree that the naming convention is wrong.  That's why I put the url to the source for that object.  In my code I actually have the inspections disabled `//ReSharper disable All` and `#pragma warning disable CS8618`.  I prefer to do that when there's online code, that way if someone picks up where I left off, they can go to that link and just copy and paste any updates they find.

Comment: Also, I know about the wrapper.  I was hoping no one would point that out, but I copied the line of code after trying to unwrap it.  When I have it unwrapped, I get ajaxSettings not found.  Good eye.

Comment: So now I think I know how he got that schema with improper naming conventions.  I actually grabbed the payload and put it into a site for converting from JSON to C# objects and got pretty much the same thing.  Still getting the same error even after doing that.  And I just pressed "Replay XHR" after updating it.  So now I'm really stumped.

Comment: I added an edit to my question.  I fixed it, but how is a still a mystery.

Comment: @Bluebaron your working snippet removes the wrapper in post call as my first suggestion.

Comment: I tried it with the wrapper, too, and it also works.

Comment: Looks like you got rid of the extra "ajaxsettings" in the request... one had a name/value of ajaxsettings, and object of your ajaxsettings object ("{ajaxSettings: ajaxSettings}")... so an extra dimension.  The second call you posted just sends the object ajaxSettings.